# Imagen Drawable en objeto java

Tags: android, imagen, objeto

Como puedo introducir un elemento drawable(en este caso una imagen) en un objeto java?

En este caso aqui:

```
public Receta(String nombre, String elaboracion, String dificultad, String ingredientes, Drawable imagen) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.elaboracion = elaboracion;
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;

}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "insertar"? Puedes crear un atributo y asignarlo en el constructor,  igual que ya hace tu código con los otros 4 atributos. Pero eso solo te dejará el valor allí, luego usarlo ya es otra cosa.

Comment: Quería decir que como uso ese elemento drawable para mostrar la imagen de un objeto.

Comment: Lo que vos querés es tener entre los datos de la receta la imagen del plato como para mostrarla por ejemplo en un RecyclerView o en el detalle de Receta. Sería eso no?

Comment: exacto, ¿como lo haría?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si las recetas son fijas, es decir que las imágenes van empaquetadas en la aplicación (apk) en la carpeta `res/drawable`, entonces podes guardar la referencia a la imagen con su `R.drawable.<nombre>` que viene a ser un campo int.

```
public Receta(String nombre, String elaboracion, String dificultad, String ingredientes, int imagen) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.elaboracion = elaboracion;
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
    this.imagen = imagen;
}
```

Luego si, por ejemplo, tenés la imagen `R.drawable.fideos_con_tuco` en `res/drawable`:

```
Receta receta = new Receta("Fideos con tuco", "Hervir el agua ...", 
                            "Muy Fácil", "Fideos, ...",
                            R.drawable.fideos_con_tuco);
```

Cuando quieras usar la imagen, por ejemplo en un ImageView: `imageView.setImageResource(receta.getImagen()); //supongo que tendrás un getImagen() en Receta.`

Por otro lado, si es el caso es que son recetas dinámicas, es decir que es el usuario el que las crea, entonces las imágenes no van a estar en `res/drawable` y la forma de resolver el tema es totalmente diferente, dado que tendrías que guardar una referencia a donde la app guarda la imagen, presumiblemente bajada de un servidor.

Por tu pregunta igualmente me parece que tu caso es el primero.

Comment: Era el primer caso, muchas gracias genio!